# Flutter: I get an error when running the official document unit test sample

Tags: flutter

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/unit/introduction
I am trying to run the unit test sample on the above page as is,
When I run it, I get an error.

```
flu_basic/
  lib/
    main.dart
  test/
    counter_test.dart
```

```
//main.dart

class Counter {
  int value = 0;

  void increment() => value++;

  void decrement() => value--;
}
```

```
//counter_test.dart

import 'package:test/test.dart';
import 'package:flu_basic/main.dart';

void main() {
  group('Counter', () {
    test('value should start at 0', () {
      expect(Counter().value, 0);
    });

    test('value should be incremented♉️', () {
      final counter = Counter();

      counter.increment();

      expect(counter.value, 1);
    });

    test('value should be decremented', () {
      final counter = Counter();

      counter.decrement();

      expect(counter.value, -1);
    });
  });
}
```

```
//part of dev_dependencies of pubspec.yaml file
dev_dependencies:
  test: ^1.15.3
```

When I run the following in terminal

```
flutter test test/counter_test.dart
```

```
Running "flutter pub get" in flu_basic...                           0.6s
00:00 +0: loading /Users/userno1/dev2/flu_basic/test/counter_test.dart                                                     
Error: cannot run without a dependency on "package:flutter_test". Ensure the following lines are present in your
pubspec.yaml:

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


00:00 +0 -1: loading /Users/userno1/dev2/flu_basic/test/counter_test.dart [E]                                              
  Failed to load "/Users/userno1/dev2/flu_basic/test/counter_test.dart":
  Compilation failed
  Test: /Users/userno1/dev2/flu_basic/test/counter_test.dart
  Shell: /Users/userno1/dev2/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/darwin-x64/flutter_tester


00:00 +0 -1: Some tests failed.
```

I get the above error.

part of dev_dependencies of pubspec.yaml file　like below↓

```
dev_dependencies:
  #test: ^1.15.3  ←comment out
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

```
00:00 +0: loading /Users/userno1/dev2/flu_basic/test/counter_test.dart                                                     Error: Could not resolve the package 'test' in 'package:test/test.dart'.
test/counter_test.dart:4:8: Error: Not found: 'package:test/test.dart'
import 'package:test/test.dart';
       ^
00:02 +0: loading /Users/userno1/dev2/flu_basic/test/counter_test.dart                                                     test/counter_test.dart:10:7: Error: Method not found: 'expect'.
      expect(Counter().value, 0);
      ^^^^^^
test/counter_test.dart:9:5: Error: Method not found: 'test'.
    test('value should start at 0', () {
    ^^^^
test/counter_test.dart:18:7: Error: Method not found: 'expect'.
      expect(counter.value, 1);
      ^^^^^^
test/counter_test.dart:13:5: Error: Method not found: 'test'.
    test('value should be incremented♉️', () {
    ^^^^
test/counter_test.dart:26:7: Error: Method not found: 'expect'.
      expect(counter.value, -1);
      ^^^^^^
test/counter_test.dart:21:5: Error: Method not found: 'test'.
    test('value should be decremented', () {
    ^^^^
test/counter_test.dart:8:3: Error: Method not found: 'group'.
  group('Counter', () {
  ^^^^^
00:06 +0 -1: loading /Users/userno1/dev2/flu_basic/test/counter_test.dart [E]                                              
  Failed to load "/Users/userno1/dev2/flu_basic/test/counter_test.dart":
  Compilation failed
  Test: /Users/userno1/dev2/flu_basic/test/counter_test.dart
  Shell: /Users/userno1/dev2/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/darwin-x64/flutter_tester


00:06 +0 -1: Some tests failed.
```

I get the above error.

Maybe on the page above

1.Add the test dependency

I think it's a problem with the part, but I don't know what to do.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only use the `test` package If you’re working on a Dart package that does not depend on Flutter. From the look of it, your project requires flutter so rather than the dev dependencies you're using at the moment, you should use the following

```yaml
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

and import the `flutter_test` package

`import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

dev_dependencies:
   flutter_test:
     sdk: flutter

When I rewrite dev_dependencies as above and run,

00:00 +0: loading /Users/userno1/dev2/flu_basic/test/counter_test.dart Error: Could not resolve the package'test' in'package:test/test.dart'.
test/counter_test.dart:4:8: Error: Not found:'package:test/test.dart'
import'package:test/test.dart';


I got the above error.

Comment: Please tell me how to start a new line in the comment field.

Comment: I don't know a a way to start a new line in comments

Comment: did you change the import statement in your counter_test.dart file to what I specified in the last line of my answer

Comment: I was able to execute it by rewriting the import statement in the counter_test.dart file with the import statement you showed me.
Thank you very much.